# next.js server side does not redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When the POST API comes to the path /frontend/response As in the code below, when console.log(formData) has valid data, it does not redirect to the specified page.

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export async function POST(request) {
    try {
        const formData = await request.formData()
        console.log(formData)

        return NextResponse.redirect(`${process.env.BOOKING_URL}/booking-confirmed`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        
    }
    
}
```

I tried to fix this problem many times but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `console.log(process.env.BOOKING_URL)` and verify the url is correct.

Comment: it's correct, I just tried to notice that when it redirects, it's still in the post method (I looked in the network tab), so it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: is any error is logged?

Comment: it's no error but it stuck doesn't not redirect, i don't know why

Comment: how about change it to just ```redirect(`${process.env.BOOKING_URL}/booking-confirmed`);```

Comment: if use redirect it's error Error: NEXT_REDIRECT / error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:266:61)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)